# Can German embassy in Malaysia return my passport for a short travel when I'm still applying for visa?

Tags: visas, passports, germany, malaysian-citizens

I submitted my passport during visa approval at German Embassy in Malaysia on 2nd August 2016 and was told I might get my passport back in 6 weeks which probably gonna be 12 September 2016. But I have to travel to Zurich on 1st September 2016. Everything is already planned; the return tickets, the hotel and business appointments and meetings. Can I get the embassy to return my passport for short travel or should I apply for a temporary passport? If so, how long do the temporary passport can be approved?

Comment: You're applying for a visa from Germany; don't you also need a visa for your trip to Switzerland?

Comment: @phoog we Malaysians don't need a visa to Switzerland for a short stay :)

Comment: You hadn't stated that you were Malaysian.  Since you are a citizen of an Annex II country, your best option is probably to explain your situation to the consulate and find out whether they can get your passport to you in time for your trip.  Then you can post an answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, your passeport is held in the embassy for the visa process. However, such a long duration - 6 weeks - may mean that your documents need to be sent to Germany. This depends on the procedures of the embassy. 
In both cases, you cannot take your document back while the visa prossess is underway. You will need to wait until it is finished.
Why didn't you ask them when submitting your documents? =) 
Anyway, just call them and explain your situation. If your passport is in the embassy and stays there - they might be able to finish your application before September. Good luck!